# separate the result based on name into different temp table in sql stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am having a result which contain name,city and address.Note:One user(name) can have more than one city and address.
I want to store the result based on name in one temporary table for one user(name) and second temporary table for second user(name) like this.I dont want hardcoded user(name)in where condition.
Can any one tell me how to do this?

Please check this images:-

[image: Current data]

[image: Expected data]

Comment: Can you explain to us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Why do you want that? Sounds like an [xy problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). There may be a better way to solve your task. To do this, you'd need dynamic sql, which is tricky and will make maintenance very difficult.

Comment: Also, please don't add data (or code) as (link to) images. Images are not searchable, and we can't copy paste for our own tests. Use (formatted) text.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sql server

Comment: @HoneyBadger ok thanks

Comment: @HoneyBadger I want to store every users infomartion on different temp tables because I need it further

Comment: @SharanaiyyaSwami but why do you need a temp table for each user?

Comment: @HoneyBadger I want to export data for one user data in one sheet and second user data in another sheet in single excel file.Is their any other way but I want the data from stored proce